# Return array from class method in objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, macos, core-data

I am facing a strange problem
Following is my code

---

This class method fetches all the model-object of type Person

```
+ (NSArray *) getAllFavourite
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [KSDatabaseHelper managedObjectContext];

    NSArray *items = [KSDatabaseHelper fetchEntitiesForClass:[Person class] withPredicate:nil inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSLog(@"getAllFavourite returning %@", items);
    return items;
}
```

**This selector logs following:**
2014-08-28 13:59:37.030 XYZ[10927:303] getAllFavourite returning (
    "[Name = michael] [City = pune]" <- This comes from the Person description
)

---

This method gives some **unexpected** logs

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [KSDatabaseHelper managedObjectContext];

        NSLog(@"List %@", [KSPeopleManager getAllFavourite]);//class method call
    }
    return self;
}
```

**This selector logs following:**
2014-08-28 13:59:37.031 XYZ[10927:303] List (
    "[Name = (null)] [City = (null)]" <- This comes from the Person description
)

---

Person class is subtype of NSManagedObject which is auto generated using from editor options for xcdatamodel
Its declaration is as follows:

---

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * city;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

- (void) setName:(NSString *)name andCity:(NSString *) city;

@end
```

---

The second log has correct array information but the objects inside the array are getting deallocated I guess.

Comment: Show the declaration of the `Person` class.

Comment: @trojanfoe : Person class is subtype of NSManagedObject which is auto generated using from editor options for xcdatamodel

Comment: All looks OK.  I have no idea.

Comment: I think that the NSManagedObjectContext returns proxies for the actual stored objects. That way the objects can be lazy loaded when needed. Perhaps this is the cause of the deallocation issues? Sorry that I cannot help you with a solution, but perhaps this info might help you figure out your issue.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs Yeah that might be the problem. Even copy selector is not working on that class. Anyways thanks